# How overriding jQuery Functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm starting to study how to create plugins, and I found the `jquery-boilerplate`, made by Zeno Rocha -- https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/jquery.boilerplate.js.

There is a function `yourOtherFunction` that is executed during `init()`, but for the sake of understanding how extending and/or overwriting works, I would like to change the behavior of this function, but this "change" made from somewhere else, something like:

```
$(".playground").defaultPluginName({
  yourOtherFunction: function() {
    console.log('yourOtherFunction extendend');
  }
});
```

Precisely I would like to have some basic functions (2 or more) in my plugin, but I would like to change your behavior, but without changing the original plugin code.

Evidently I found several posts mentioning how to extend/overwrite, but as I'm starting to study, I couldn't understand it simply and practically.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Create a Basic Plugin](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), this might help you to understand on how to start

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... yes ... I did the reading before posting my question, but from what I saw in the document, as I understood it, I need to define an empty anonymous function in variable, but looking at other plugins, I don't see this kind of structure, of course I understand there are several ways to do it, but I would like to try to start in a more appropriate way